# Retention and archival policy on Hive data

Tags: amazon-web-services, hive, amazon-emr

We have an AWS EMR which includes a Hive backed by aurora metadata and data stored in s3. There are programs that create the database(s) and tables inside in Hive and populate data.

After a while, these databases are no longer needed (say after 1 year). We want to delete those hive databases automatically after a set period. The usual way is to set a cron job that runs every month or so, to find the databases from an internal metadata table that are older than 1 year, and programmatically fire the queries in Hive which deletes it. But this has some drawbacks like Manually created tables are not being covered.

Is there any hive built-in feature that does the above?

Answer (score 0):

Hive is actually just a metadata store that defines how data should be interpreted.  It does not manage any of the underlying data.  (This is a major difference between hive and a conventional database. And why hive can use multiple file backends(hdfs&S3) in the same hive instance.)

I'm going to guess you are using an s3 bucket for you data so you likely want to look into [expiring objects](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/lifecycle-expire-general-considerations.html).  This will do exactly what you want. Delete data after a period of time.  This will not disrupt hive.

If you are using partitions you may wish to do some additional cleanup.

`MSCK REPAIR TABLE` will help maintain the partitions in hive but is really slow in S3 and periodically can timeout. YMMV.

It's better to drop partitions:

```
ALTER TABLE bills DROP IF EXISTS PARTITION (mydate='2022-02') PURGE;
```

Comment: Matt , Thanks for the answer. The link you've provided for expiring objects will work for only clearing the s3 data. But it won't clear the Aurora metastore which is located outside of the EMR cluster. So basically you'll still be able to find the database names querying "show databases" in hive, also  the related meta data in aurora.
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/emr/latest/ReleaseGuide/emr-hive-metastore-external.html

Comment: You are correct, it will clean up the data it & Partitions but it will not remove the databases.  I guess it's a unique concept that one would have a database that would require removal.  It makes sense that if a database has "No Data" what is it's use. But I would be concerned that you may delete databases that may have data that is under a "say a year" old but the data base is older than a year old.  Do you see the danger? (Its your risk to accept)

Answer (score 0):

In Hive you can implement [partitions retention](https://docs.cloudera.com/HDPDocuments/HDP3/HDP-3.1.4/using-hiveql/content/hive-set-partition-retention.html) (since Hive 3.1.0)

For example to drop partitions and their data after 7 days:

```
ALTER TABLE employees SET TBLPROPERTIES ('partition.retention.period'='7d');
```

Comment: leftjoin - Thanks for the answer. Will this also drop the aurora metadata located outside the EMR ?
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/emr/latest/ReleaseGuide/emr-hive-metastore-external.html

Comment: @Tomin It should not depend on which metastore database is used. Hive just uses JDBC connection to metastore DB

Answer (score 0):

There is not a hive internal tool that removes 'databases' according to a "retention period" in hive.

You have been doing this for a while so you are likely well aware of the risks of deleting metadata older than a year.

There are several ways to define retention on data, but none that I'm aware to remove metadata.

Things you could look at:
You could add a trigger to Aurora to delete tables directly from the hive metadata.  (Hive tables have values for create time and they're last access time) you could create some logic to work at that level.